# Xcode Swift How do i rotate a portrait image to landscape

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Hope someone can help me.

I have a imagepicker where pictures are taken as a portrait . My image is then displayed in an UIImageView where the width is greater than the height which makes the image looks wrong . How can I show the picture in my uiimageview in the landscape ? Is it possible to rotate the image in the imageview ?

my code for imagepicker are:

```
func openCamera() {

    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self .presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        openGallary()
    }
}

func openGallary() {

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: imagePicker)
    }
}

internal func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    imageView.image = image

    photoURL = saveImageToFile(image)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```